# Is there an "or" in XPath selectors?

Tags: php, xpath

I am having the following xPath that gets image from `<div class="separator">`. My question is how can I make the xPath to search in `<div class="entry">` also?

```
$img = $xpath->query('//div[@class="separator"]//img');
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$img = $xpath->query('//div[@class="separator" or @class="entry"]//img');
```

Comment: Hi thanks it works! However I have another small question `$posts = $xPath->query('//item');

foreach($posts as $post) {
$title = $post->getnode('title'); ` 
what sould I put instead of `getnode` (it's wrong) to get the <title> value from <item> ?

Comment: @Mikey try `nodeValue` property if you want the text node of an HTML element. If you want the `title` element, try `getElementsByTagName('title')`.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks again. It really helped me and changed correctly my entire code based on your answer! However I have a small question about attribute, if you have time take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467957/error-on-getting-src-attribute-question-on-how-to-get-the-path-correctly]

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = $xpath->query('//div[@class="separator"]//img | //div[@class="entry"]//img');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = $xpath->query('//div[@class="separator" or @class='entry']//img');
```