# Error on getting src attribute. ( question on how to get the path correctly )

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to get some data from a RSS feed but I am having problem on getting the src attribute of img. 
The image is located at  `//item/description/div[@class="separator"]//img` and one attempt I made is to join the posts xPath having

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-line XPath solution. :)

Comment: What is the meaning of "but I am having problem "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There :

```
$imagespath = $IMAGES->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

You are getting the content of some `<description>` tag into the `$imagespath` variable.

That variable, so, doesn't contain a `DOMElement` nor any kind of object, but some string content.

Then, you try to call the `getAttribute()` method on that variable :

```
$image = $imagespath->getAttribute('src');
```

But as `$imagespath` is not an object *(it's a string)*, you get a Fatal Error.

If you want to get the `src` attribute of some tag, I suppose you should get it with something like this :

```
$image = $IMAGES->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

i.e. reading the `src` attribute of a node returned by your XPath query -- of course, before calling `getAttribute()`, you should check that there is actually an item returned by the query.

Also, if you want to load images, maybe you should get `<img>` tags :

```
$IMAGES = $post->getElementsByTagName( "img" );
```

And not `<description>` ones ?

Comment: edited Hi, thanks! How can I read the src attribut befor the getAttrbute? `$image = $IMAGES->item(0)->getAttribute('src');` it didn't work....

Comment: Came here to answer, but can't really add anything to this good answer :) +1

Comment: @alexHi again, I mean that the example above(and thanks for this) it can't worked

Answer (score 0):

If the `someExpr` XPath expression selects a single element `someElem`, then the following XPath expression:

```
someExpr/@src
```

selects the `src` attribute of the `someElem` element (if it has a `src` attribute).

**In your case**:

```
//item/description/div[@class="separator"]//img/@src
```